# How do I interact with Windows programs

Tags: python, winapi, com

So I'm trying to create an automatic installer using Python. How would I go about interacting with native Windows applications that I launch? I am currently launching them using subprocess.call. Would I need to use Win32com? IronPython? Call a VB script from Python?

I've been trying to look into COM objects, but all I see are default Microsoft applications.

Comment: What are these native Windows applications your installer launches? Do they accept command-line arguments so you can tell them what to do without having to automate their UI?

Comment: Doubtful, though I can look into that. Snagit, Camtasia, Gotomeeting, Ninite installer, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the application supports COM, use COM using [`win32com`](http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/Downloads.html). This [tutorial](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html) helped me a lot. If it does not, you can use something like [`pywinauto`](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) or similar software. It is usually described as module for GUI testing. [`SendKeys`](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/) comes handy for non-standard GUIs as a last resort.

[Ranorex Spy](http://www.ranorex.com/gui-testing-guide/spy.html) is very helpful tool for identifying GUI elements.

Some of my colleagues also use compiled [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) scripts.

Comment: I have used SendKeys before when I needed to do something like this before, but that was very, very messy.

Comment: Pywinauto looks phenomenal! Going to test it now.

Comment: SendKeys is messy but sometimes it is the only way. However at least when called from Pywinauto it gives the focus to the right window.